# Copying and pasting one canvas inside another canvas's corner

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have two canvases on my HTML page and what i actually want to do is pasting all stuff inside first canvas in bottom right corner of second canvas. 
This is the code I was trying:

```
<canvas id="first"></canvas>
<canvas id="second"></canvas>
<script>
var first = document.getElementById('first').getContext('2d');
var sec = document.getElementById('second').getContext('2d');

//--code for drawing in first canvas--

var img = new Image();
img.src="imgName.jpg";
img.onload = function() {
    sec.drawImage(img,0,0,sec.canvas.width,sec.canvas.height);

//Actually i want first canvas to overlap image on second canvas

    var paste = new Image();
    paste.src = first.canvas;
    paste.onload = function() {

        sec.drawImage(paste,100,100,400,600);

    };
};
</script>
```

Problem is: second canvas shows image but doesn't shows first canvas in its bottom right corner.

**Please** worthy guys, i need the answer. Its very Important.   Thanks in advnce to all helpers..

Comment: console tab says "failed to load:first.canvas"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are drawing the first canvas on the second one is not correct. You can directly draw a canvas on another canvas using `drawImage()` method.

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first').getContext('2d');
var sec = document.getElementById('second').getContext('2d');

// draw on first canvas
first.fillStyle = '#07C';
first.fillRect(0, 0, first.canvas.width, first.canvas.height);

// draw image on second canvas
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/300/300";
img.onload = function() {
   sec.drawImage(img, 0, 0, sec.canvas.width, sec.canvas.height);
   sec.drawImage(first.canvas, 100, 100, 100, 100); // draw first canvas on a portion of second canvas
};
```

```css
body {display: flex}
```

```html
<canvas id="first" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="second" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: what is {display:flex;} for?

Comment: just for the styling, so you can see both canvases side by side on the snippet. you don't need to worry about it